# Problem with the size of key to encrypth with 3des

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

I´m trying to encripth with 3des with the next code:

```
+ (NSData *)tripleDesEncryptString:(NSString *)input
                           key:(NSString *)key
                         error:(NSError **)error
{
    NSParameterAssert(input);
    NSParameterAssert(key);

    NSData *inputData = [input dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    size_t outLength;

    NSAssert(keyData.length == kCCKeySize3DES, @"the keyData is an invalid size");

    NSMutableData *outputData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:(inputData.length  +  kCCBlockSize3DES)];

   CCCryptorStatus
   result = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, // operation
                 kCCAlgorithm3DES, // Algorithm
                 kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode, // options
                 keyData.bytes, // key
                 keyData.length, // keylength
                 nil,// iv
                 inputData.bytes, // dataIn
                 inputData.length, // dataInLength,
                 outputData.mutableBytes, // dataOut
                 outputData.length, // dataOutAvailable
                 &outLength); // dataOutMoved

    if (result != kCCSuccess) {
        if (error != NULL) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.your_domain.your_project_name.your_class_name."
                                     code:result
                                 userInfo:nil];
        }
    return nil;
    }
    [outputData setLength:outLength];
    return outputData;
}
```

The key to use must be 24 bytes length, but the server return a simetric key more long than 24 bytes. For example: asb6kl92-98k7-6ike-a8e5-2299775b3334. I dont know how to convert this key to valid key to my algorithm. Any idea?

Comment: That's not a key, that's a UUID (which represents a 16 byte number; what you've given is just a common encoding of it). You'll need to discuss with whoever develops the server what the intent of that result is. How you convert this to a key completely depends on how it will be decrypted. The encryption and decryption systems have to match. The code you've posted here is also very insecure; why do you think it should be encrypted this way?

Comment: (It's possible that you're using this insecure approach because the decryptor requires it, and I completely understand that. But in that case, you hopefully have access to the decryptor to be able to construct the encryptor.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. Cold you tell me why te code is insecure?

Comment: You can't just take a string and turn it into a key like this; it drastically shrinks the keyspace even if the key is random. ECB mode, which is horribly broken for anything non-random, longer than one block. 3DES itself is very dodgy, and is unacceptable for encrypting more than 8M with same key (Sweet32 attack). There is no reason to use 3DES today except for backward compatibility. New systems should use AES unless you have a very specialized problem and a solid crypto background to evaluate an other option.